# The following function $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at $x = 5$

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me solve this or give me a hint on how to start I am not sure how to proceed.

The following function $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at $x = 5$. Find a function $g(x)$ that agrees with $f(x)$ for all $x ≠ 5$ and is continuous at $x = 5$.

$$f(x)=\frac{x^4-4x^3-2x^2-19x+20}{x-5}$$

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax rather than posting pictures. Pictures are not indexed by a search engine, and hence cannot be looked up, which is the purpose of this forum itself.

Comment: use synthetic division

Comment: in order for $g(x)$ to be continuous, we need $g(5)=\lim\limits_{x\to5} g(x)$

Comment: You are already given the value of $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\ne5$. You simply need to find $g(5)$ and since $g$ is continuous, we have $g(5)=\lim_{x\to5}g(x)=\lim_{x\to5}f(x)$ as in the limit $x$ only tends to $5$ but never equals it.

Comment: alright thanks i got it from that and managed to solve it

Comment: you could post your solution as an answer to your question